# How can we need internal mailbox in magento for customers so that they can send mail to other customers from their account?

Tags: magento, account

What are the steps to integrate internal mailbox for customers in magento so that they can send mail to other customers from their account on the site?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following?

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html

however I didn't check for magento 1.5+

Comment: Yes I am working on it.But we want to have customer internal mailbox on front-end so that user can send Emails from their account after logging-In.Is there any way o have internal mailbox on frontend.